# React grid layout not working with firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I changed my code so that it would bring in the information from cloud firestore instead of hardcoding it. This is my old code without firebase:

```
<div className="grid">
                <div className="grid-child">
                  <img className="subImg" src={amsterdam}></img>
                  <p className="subImgTitle">Amsterdam</p>
                  <p className="subImgText">Hotels from £?</p>
                </div>
                <div className="grid-child">
                  <img className="subImg" src={london}></img>
                  <p className="subImgTitle">London</p>
                  <p className="subImgText">Hotels from £?</p>
                </div>
                <div className="grid-child">
                  <img className="subImg" src={madrid}></img>
                  <p className="subImgTitle">Madrid</p>
                  <p className="subImgText">Hotels from £?</p>
                </div>
                <div className="grid-child">
                  <img className="subImg" src={paris}></img>
                  <p className="subImgTitle">Paris</p>
                  <p className="subImgText">Hotels from £?</p>
                </div>
              </div>
```

And this is my new code with firebase:

```
destinations?.map(destination => {
          return (
            <div className="grid">
              <div className="grid-child">
                <img className="subImg" src={destination.img}></img>
                <p className="subImgTitle">{destination.title}</p>
                <p className="subImgText">Hotels from £{destination.price}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })
```

In the original code, the images are all in a row however now they are all in one column. I am not too sure how to fix this so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compare the DOM rendered by each example, you will see that the problem is that in the first example you have a single `<div className="grid">` but in the second you wrap each image in `<div className="grid">`. To fix this, just be sure to create only one `grid`:

```
<div className="grid">
{ destinations?.map(destination => {
          return (
              <div className="grid-child">
                <img className="subImg" src={destination.img}></img>
                <p className="subImgTitle">{destination.title}</p>
                <p className="subImgText">Hotels from £{destination.price}</p>
              </div>
          )
        })
}
</div>
```

As a next step, consider refactoring a `GridChild` component that encapsulates the HTML for each image in the grid.